# Passing array value to option value

Tags: php

I  am looping over an array and passing these values to a select list as follows

```
<select class="form-control  chzn-select">
   <?php  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      echo "<option>" . $row['schoolname'] . "</option>";
     }?>  
  </select>
```

I have to pass `$row['schoolcode'] in <option value='here'>`. How do I do that?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?  And what is wrong with the code you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<option value='" . $row['schoolcode'] . "'>" . $row['schoolname'] . "</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

What does this have to do with jQuery?

Are you trying to do the following:

```
echo '<option value="' . $row['schoolcode'] . '">' . $row['schoolname'] . '</option>';
```

Also: Try to separate logic from presentation. (A common way to do so is the MVC or MVVM way) It is not good to communicate with the database while building the html. (What happens on an error? You cannot redirect and will send an incomplete or wrong html)